# How to add layer to OpenLayers, but without it getting automatically added in LayerSwitcher Control?

Tags: openlayers

I have a Openlayer web map with LayerSwitcher control added. I need this to switch some of my layers. But I am also adding and removing some layers, which are temperory and i donot want them added to the LayerSwitcher Control. 
So is there a way to add layer to OpenLayers, but without it getting automatically added in LayerSwitcher Control?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured this out.  I need to add 'displayInLayerSwitcher: false' in the layer options.